# eos default eosio account, why is it already created? what it's its main purpose?

Tags: accounts

I'm creating new accounts with cleos, I've noticed there is an account already present called "eosio". What is the main use the eosio account? is it essential or can i delete it?

Comment: all accounts need to have an owner, so `eosio` can be used to create other accounts and is typically used to push the `eosio.*` contracts as well and act as a multisig superuser